# not only show eclipse plugin popup within package explorer

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm pretty new to eclipse plugin development but it's working fine so far except the part that my plugin does only show in java or plugin development perspective.

this is related to the following locationURI:

```
locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer?after=additions"
```

an other perspective uses "Navigator" for example therefore my plugin does not show.

how am I able to make it visible in Navigator (don't know the locationURI for it) and Project Explorer too (popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
```

to contribute to any popup menu which has an 'additions' position.

Comment: exactly what I've been looking for.
thanks for the fast response !